# Subsetting a data from within a function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset

I am aware that this question has quite a few answers and I have been reading them since 10AM this morning (it's 5PM here now).

I've been trying to figure out, which I thought would be simple, how to subset a data frame from within my function. All I'm trying to do is print out the vector that would ideally be produced by subsetting the DF. The issue I am having is I use the same `desired_column_name` elsewhere referencing the data frame directly and as such, I cannot just "add quotations" to my argument. I attempted adding quotations to the `desired_column_name` argument and then applying `noquote` from within the function but that didn't work either and made things worse.

Here are the simple inputs I'm using:

```
S = c(1,0,0,4,1,6,6,3,5,3,1)
population = data.frame(S)
```

Here is the code for reference:

```
proportion_of_elements= function(df_for_use, desired_column_name, desired_elements,logical){     

  DF = df_for_use

  chr_desired_column_name = as.character(desired_column_name)

  desired_column =  DF[,chr_desired_column_name]


  vec_length = length(desired_column)
  num_of_desired_element = sum(desired_column == desired_elements)
  proportion = num_of_desired_element/vec_length


  statement_for_pop_prop = c("The proportion of ", desired_elements,'\'s', "from the population is: ", proportion)
  format_vers_of_statement_for_pop_prop = str_c(statement_for_pop_prop, collapse = " ")

  # summary = summarize(data_frame, mean = mean(desired_column_name, na.rm = TRUE), var = var(desired_column_name, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(desired_column_name, na.rm = TRUE))
  # 
  # statement_of_summary = c("The summary statistics are the following: ", summary)
  # 
  # format_of_summary = str_c(statement_of_summary, collapse = " ")

  #print(format_vers_of_statement_for_pop_prop)
   print(desired_column)

}
```

Reproducible Example:

```
proportion_of_elements(population,S,1,FALSE)
```

Desired output:

```
1 0 0 4 1 6 6 3 5 3 1
```

Current Output:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(DF, , chr_desired_column_name) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

As mentioned before, I can get the desired output, but that would require me putting quotations around the `desired_column_name` argument which would result in everything else breaking.

As you can see, I also attempted another suggested solution of redefining the data frame itself within the function. I tried this using `DF`. The commented out code is the part that uses `desired_column_name` without quotation marks.

If my code is too convulated, I apologize. The main issue I'm seeing has to do with how `desired_column` is being interpreted. So that is the part to focus on.

Thanks to everybody that provides any suggestions.

**EDIT**

After the suggestion given by G. Grothendieck, I edited my code and got the following error:

Comment: You need a reproducible example. Show us what you have and what you want to produce.

Comment: will edit...right now

Comment: That's the issue I'm having. it cannot be with quotations. In the commented out section of my code, I reference the column of the data frame and it that situation it uses `S` without quotations.

Comment: are you sure your desired output is `1 0 0 4 1 6 6 3 5 3 1` instead of `1 4 1 6 6 0 1 0 1` ?

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan copied it exactly out of R when I tweaked the code to produce the result

Comment: You say 'vector that would ideally be produced by subsetting the DF' but I do not see any subsetting in your output? Can you please elaborate on what you are actually doing?

Comment: perhaps I'm using the wrong term, if that is the case sorry. So the variable  is `desired_column =  DF[,chr_desired_column_name]`. What I want to do is take that column from the data frame (which considers it a vector) and use that vector in the `vec_length = length(desired_column)` variable that I defined.

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do. What is the use of `logical` argument that you are passing ?  What is your input and what is your expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah I was able to tidy up the function with some help from G. Grothendieck. I do have another question I am about to post with respect to R MArkdown right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want something like this:

```
prop_elem <- function(data, col, elem) {

  prop <- mean(data[[col]] == elem, na.rm = TRUE)
  cat("The proportion of", elem, "in column", col, "is", prop, "\n")

  Mean <- mean(data[[col]], na.rm = TRUE)
  cat("The mean of column", col, "is", Mean, "\n")

  data[[col]]
}

prop_elem(population, "S", 1)
```

giving:

```
The proportion of 1 in column S is 0.2727273 
The mean of column S is 2.727273 
 [1] 1 0 0 4 1 6 6 3 5 3 1
```

Comment: yes....that is what I wanted. What did the double brackets on `data[[col]]` do to the data frame? and also why state it at the very end as well?

Comment: If `col` is the name of a column then `data[[col]]` is that column.

Comment: Actually I tried the edit you posted but I'm still getting issues: `desired_column =  df_for_use[[desired_column_name]]
  
vec_length = length(df_for_use[[desired_column_name]])
  num_of_desired_element = sum(df_for_use[[desired_column_name]] == desired_elements)`

Error reported:

`Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2  `

Comment: All I did was replace the `desired_column_name` with the version you inputted `[[desired_column_name]]`.

Comment: Would the reproducible code fit in a comment though?